# Physics of a helium balloon

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, gas

I found a helium balloon in the mountains on the ground that fell from the sky. Threw it in the back of the ATV like trash and returned home. 3 days later found it floating still attached to the string stuck on a rock, on a freezing frigid morning, 29 degrees. Explain the physics behind this please.

Comment: The density of the helium in the balloon is a function of temperature (essentially an ideal gas). The density of air is a function of both temperature and humidity. Dry air is denser than moist air. Absolute humidity at 29F is pretty darn low, so the air got denser so the balloon could float again.

Comment: @JonCuster Have you not written an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The ballon rises, falls, or floats (without rising or falling) depending on its buoyancy which, in turn, depends on whether the density of the balloon is less than, greater than, or equal to the density of the surrounding air, respectively.

When you found the balloon on the ground on top of the mountain it's likely because it lost some of its helium through the balloon material (due to its porosity), making the density of the balloon higher than the density of the surrounding air.

You found it floating in your ATV on a cold morning because the density of the air in your ATV became greater than the density of the balloon, due to the colder air temperature (though you didn't say what the temperature was atop the mountain), possibly combined with the increase in air density due to the lower altitude.

Hope this helps.